# How to remove the context path when viewing authenticated content

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

I'm working on a grails application that sits on a server with another root.war application.  Currently we use apache redirects to hide the context path (name of our grails application) as we already have a root.war and we don't want it to show on all our urls.  This works for our public content.  However, now that we've added some authenticated content with spring security core plugin it always redirects to include the context path.  Hence, the url /authcontent/page.gsp is getting redirected to /appname/authcontent/page.gsp.  Some folks have mentioned you can remove the context path by creating a separate virtual host in tomcat, but I was wondering if there's a way to override the mechanism that Spring Security uses to do the redirect in the filter chain.  Perhaps overriding the RequestCacheAwareFilter? but I believe that filter only is used after the initial authentication.  I've read through the spring security documentation but it doesn't talk as much about redirecting requests as much as the whole authentication and authorization process so I'm wondering if this is in the plugin itself.  Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's number of ways of doing this.  Two I tried were overriding the `requestCache` bean (but then you also had to override the `DefaultSavedRequest`) and overriding the `redirectStategy` bean which is what I'm using as it was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the app context in the **Config.groovy** file:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080"
        grails.app.context = "/"
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        grails.serverURL = "http://yourwebsite.com"
        grails.app.context = "/"
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @adavis, unfortunately my understanding is that the grails.app.context is only used when you use grails run-app.  When deploying as a war file the context path is determined by the container so this property doesn't get used.

Comment: I tested it with grails prod run-war, and it worked.  I would at least give it try.  Thanks!

Comment: I have thanks.  It was one of the first things I tried with no luck.